# Переход по картинке в карусели Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, slider, карусель, carousel

Как сделать переход по нажатию по картинке (в любом месте слайда) в карусели Bootstrap?
Пока что переход производится только по кнопке "Lasīt vairāk"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните содержимое слайда ссылкой. Перенесите со стилей слайда паддинги в вашу ссылку. Сделайте ссылку блочной. Пропишите для ссылки внутри слайда белый цвет (в том числе на ховер, актив, визитед). Уберите у ссылки поддчеркивание.